# unable to read values that are posted

Tags: php, html, input, output

I have a notification listner file that listens notifications form my payment processor, Im using this to read the available data thats submitted, its submitted as POST TXT

```
$message = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

when I print `$message` it prints the whole array properly like

```
Array
(
    [TRANSACTION_TYPE] => sale
    [ORDER_STATUS] => SUCCESS
    [PAYOUT_CURRENCY] => USD
    [PAYOUT_AMOUNT] => 100.00
    [TAXES_AMOUNT] => 0.00
    [TAXES_AMOUNT_USD] => 0.00
    [VOID] => Y
    [EVENT_ID] => 1
)
```

but when I use the array values in my conditions they are failing, when I print `$message['ORDER_STATUS']` this prints `A` but in the array it prints as `SUCCESS`

any idea why this value is changing when using a selected array value?

Comment: It should be $message['ORDER_STATUS'] (with quotes)

Comment: Can you show us the HTML as well? Besides what are you trying to get from the array? and it would be great if you post the code rather than just the problem here

Comment: `$message` is a string, not an array.

Comment: It looks like you're posting the output of `print_r($array, true)`. That won't work, you can't parse the output of `print_r`. Why aren't you using normal form encoding?

Comment: @Barmar seems you know whats happening, cool, it should be as text,, but Im not posting this, my payment processor is porting notification about the payment in this form to me. so I need to decode/understand this as an array to process further

Comment: There's something wrong with the payment processor. I don't know why they're sending input like that. They should send JSON or www-form-urlencoded input data, not `print_r` format.

Comment: What payment processor are you using? Do you have a link to their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If your `$message` array is like this,

```
Array
(
    [TRANSACTION_TYPE] => sale
    [ORDER_STATUS] => SUCCESS
    [PAYOUT_CURRENCY] => USD
    [PAYOUT_AMOUNT] => 100.00
    [TAXES_AMOUNT] => 0.00
    [TAXES_AMOUNT_USD] => 0.00
    [VOID] => Y
    [EVENT_ID] => 1
)
```

than try this way to get value of each index.

`$message->TRANSACTION_TYPE` it will give you  `SUCCESS`

Here, you can't access directly because it's as Object Array.